# the following feature couldn't be installed on .NET Framework 4.5 and win 2012

Tags: c#, .net, exe, .net-framework-version

I have created an exc in VS2012 (C#) using .NET 3.5 Framework.
And run that exe on test machine - Win OS 2012 .NET Framework 4.5 only 
It is giving me following message

[image: Feature Couldn't be installed]

I have following questions :
1. Why it is not supporting backward compatibility of .NET Framework 3.5 ?
2. Is there any way to handle this or user has to install 3.5 .NET Framework ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added following configuration in app.config file and it worked like charm

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
    <supportedRuntime version="V4.0" />
  </startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the project to Framework 4 of 4.5, or install 3.5 (from Server Manager) are your only options i think...

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx
for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably set .Net 3.5 as requirement at the **Installer**.

---

> The .NET Framework 4.5 is backward-compatible with applications that
>   were built with the .NET Framework versions 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, and 4.
>   In other words, applications and components built with previous
>   versions of the .NET Framework will work on the .NET Framework 4.5.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/09/26/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:d:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

where d:\ is the CD ROM drive your windows CD is in.

then try again.